# HI, I need sql Query that find out the year with custom calendar

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I Have only one columns in a table given below table name like custom_calendar_year. It has starting of the Year(custom Date, Month and years).From 1990-01-27 to 1995-01-31. If i give a input like 1991-01-01 as per the below table it should fetch the output as 1990-01-27 By system calendar it is a new year but if we search in this calendar its a year end. Kindly assist me to compare the input with this values as i know their is compare option in SQL. How to proceed.

custom_calendar_year
1990-01-27
1991-02-15
1992-04-02
1993-01-23
1994-10-02
1995-01-31

Comment: Just go through the link of DB snapshot http://prntscr.com/6gm8p8

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the next larger value for a given value, then a query like this will work:

```
select min(custom_calendar_year)
from table t
where custom_calendar_year >= '1990-01-01';
```

Comment: Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?

Comment: Sorry for the delay.Kindly go through the below link:    http://sqlfiddle.com/index.html#!8/624df/6